# Semantic issues while running unity arkit project in xcode beta

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit

I have taken a unity example and exported the project as an ios project.
But while building I am getting semantic issues as shown in picture :

[image]

Same project is working on another mac but not on my iMac.

OS Version : 10.13 Beta
Xcode Version : Xcode beta 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration` was renamed to [`ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration) in an earlier iOS 11 beta seed. (Beta 5 in early August, if I recall correctly?)

They left the old symbol around with a deprecation notice so that developers using it would have time to heed the warning and migrate to the new API. But they removed the renamed symbol in Xcode 9 GM seed.

If you have the old symbol (`ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration`) in any of your own sources, find/replace to use the new one (`ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`) instead. If you got those sources from a third party (like Unity) some time ago, make sure you're using an up-to-date version. Or if Unity is still providing out-of-date ARKit code, you might want to bug them about it...

---

(Also, if anyone was using the superclass `ARSessionConfiguration` directly to get 3DOF tracking, that got split: now [`ARConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration) is an abstract superclass, and [`AROrientationTrackingConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arorientationtrackingconfiguration) is the concrete class to get 3DOF tracking.)

Comment: Thank you for sharing. It helped!